# Delegate/Events winform c# is not working - subscriber/listener is always null

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a user control which is added in a win form (it gets added dynamically).In another class i have property and i have an event for that property that when ever it updates, notify some other part of project in this case the 
Notify the User Control. But my porblem is the Usercontrol never gets Notified. I can see that property gets updates correctly, but the event of delegate type is always null.

Here is my delegate Type

```
public delegate void Submited(bool value);
```

I have a user control, which gets added to a form and then that form is loaded on a button click. 
below is how i am adding user control to the form

```
UserDoc UserDocUserControl= new UserDoc(); //This is user control
UserDocForm UserDocWinForm = new UserDocForm(); //This is Form
UserDocWinForm.Controls.Add(UserDocUserControl);
UserDocWinForm.Show();
```

This is my UserDoc User Control

```
public partial class UserDoc : UserControl
{
    GetUserAction Var_GetUserAction = new GetUserAction();
    public UserDoc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Var_GetUserAction.DocSubmitted += OnDocSubmitted;                         
    }

    private void OnDocSubmitted(bool value)
    {
       // it never get hits
       MessageBox.Show("Event Caught");
    }   
    /// More code which is not making any difference here.........

}
```

Here is my class that's keeping eye on the property

```
public class GetUserAction
{   
    public event Submited DocSubmitted;        
    private bool _IsAllowed
    public bool IsAllowed
    {
        get { return _IsAllowed; }
        set
        {
            // _IsAllowed gets hit when ever the value is changed
            if (_IsAllowed != value)
            {
                _IsAllowed = value;
                // this DocSubmitted is always Null
                if (DocSubmitted != null)
                {
                    //It never comes here?????
                    DocSubmitted(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void SetIsAllowed()
    {
        IsAllowed = // some other code is updating this part and its working fine;
    }
}
```

Any guidance/help will be appreciate, i am not able to figure out what Am I Doing Wrong!!!

Comment: Could you please refactor this into a console app that we could just run to see the error?

Comment: @Enigmativity it has services running and would require host .. i would have done it if was simple

Comment: The `GetUserAction` object that is being updated is probably not the same one that is referenced by the `UserDoc` class. You probably mean to pass the `GetUserAction` as a reference in the `UserDoc` constructor.

Comment: @Angloos - If it's hard for you refactor your code it probably means it is hard for us to answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity its running Bunch of services that's why its hard for me to Refactor it to a New Console App... : )

Comment: Also, please change it so you don't use `TitleCase` for anything besides type names and public members. Local variables should have `camelCase` names.

Comment: @Loathing .. Awesome ... Thanks Buddy .. you wana change your comment to answer or something so i can accept it as Answer. It Worked!! 2 and Half Hour for this Stupid Mistake!!!

Comment: @Angloos - It seems like Loathing made an good educated guess. Notice that there is nothing in your code that you've provided that shows that this is problem. That's the problem with only posting what you think is relevant.

Comment: @Angloos Cool beans, posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetUserAction` object that is being updated is probably not the same one that is referenced by the `UserDoc` class. You probably mean to pass the `GetUserAction` as a reference in the `UserDoc` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you must set IsAllowed then it call event

add :

```
    public UserDoc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Var_GetUserAction.DocSubmitted += OnDocSubmitted;
        //set properties to call event
        Var_GetUserAction.IsAllowed = true;
    }
```

you can get source :
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JxRo8fyd3QbnBxVE5HdmF1bWs/view?usp=sharing